# How do you add a custom image size in Apostrophe CMS?

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I found this page in the documentation (https://docs.apostrophecms.org/apostrophe/modules/apostrophe-attachments#options), but it doesn't really explain how and where you actually use `addImageSizes`.

I tried creating an `apostrophe-attachments` folder in my modules, adding an index.js file and doing this...

```
module.exports = {
  extend: "apostrophe-module",
  imageSizes: [
    {
      name: 'tiny',
      width: 100,
      height: 100
   }
  ]
}
```

But that gives me an error, cannot read property of middleware.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `extend` when you are just improving a core module with some new configuration or project-level methods.

Using `extend` like this will break the link between your configuration of it and the original module, creating an entirely new module that has no idea how to serve attachments.

So, just write:

```
module.exports = {
  addImageSizes: [
    {
      name: 'tiny',
      width: 100,
      height: 100
   }
  ]
}
```

Leaving out `extend`.

Comment: Note that you must also use `addImageSizes`, not `imageSizes`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Tom's answer, you could also set the new image sizes globally for all modules that use the apostrophe-attachments widget in the system by putting it into `app.js`. Just add it under your declaration of widgets.

```
'apostrophe-attachments': {
      addImageSizes: [{
        name: 'tiny',
        width: 100,
        height: 100
      }]
    },
```

Regarding the usage of `imageSizes` vs. `addImageSizes`: In the comments of the apostrophe-attachments module, it states:

> Like `addImageSizes`, but Apostrophe's standard sizes are completely
>   replaced. Bear in mind // that certain sizes are used by Apostrophe's
>   editing interface unless overridden. We recommend // using
>   `addImageSizes`.

Therefore you could use `imageSizes`, replacing the out of the box image sizes, just have this in mind.